# Q/KDB+ / CSV upload and WSFULL

Tags: csv, out-of-memory, kdb

Pardon me but I'm a Q novice and couldn't find a solution. The code below appends a four-column CSV file to a KDB+ database. This code worked well but, now that my database is large, it throws a WSFULL error. Perhaps there is a more memory efficient way to write it.  Please help:

```
// FILE_LOADER.q
\c 520 500
if [(count .z.x) < 1;
    show `$"usage: q loadcsv.q inputfile destfile
        where inputfile and destfile are absolute or relative paths to 
        the files. Inputfile has the following fields:
                DATE, TICKER, FIELD, VALUE. DATE is of type date,
                TICKER and FIELD are strings, and VALUE is converted to a float.
                Any string VALUEs will show up as nulls.";
    exit 1
   ]
f1: hsym `$.z.x[0]
f2: hsym `$.z.x[1]
columns: `DATE`TICKER`FIELD`VALUE
if [() ~ key f1; show ("Input file '",.z.x[0],"' not found");exit 1]
x: .Q.fsn[{f2 upsert flip columns!("DSSF";",")0:x};f1;4194000000]
show ("loaded ",(string x)," characters into the kdb database")
exit 0
```

Comment: Did you read the definition of .Q.fsn on code.kx? https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfsn-streaming-algorithm - ".Q.fsn is almost identical to .Q.fs but takes an extra argument z, the size in bytes that chunks will be read in. This is particularly useful for balancing load speed and RAM usage". Lower value = more time but uses less RAM, higher value (which you have) = faster but higher RAM usage

Answer (score 1):

First just from trying this out I assume your input csv file never has a header? If it does you'll need a slight code change so kdb is aware.

You are correct that it's a memory issue so what you can do is just decrease the chunk size. You are reading in 4194000000 bytes at a time right now. Try lowering this in accordance with available memory.

If you are still seeing issues it may be your garbage collection setting. You could force a gc after each read/upsert.

```
.Q.fsn[{f2 upsert flip columns!("DSSF";",")0:x;**.Q.gc[]**};f1;4194000000]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I cannot seem to fail reliably to test if this solution works when the other does not.  I will confirm the solution when I can test it properly.  Thank you again.